# mysql_real_escape_string not escaping all types of ”

Tags: php, mysql

I noticed something weird with `mysql_real_escape_string` function. It does not escape`“` or `”`, for example:`“TEST”` is not converted into `\“TEST\”`.

The functions work fine with `"` (look closely and you see they are different)

Any idea how to fix this, I rather not write this function from scratch. Is it deprecated, is there an alternative?

**EDIT**: Thank you all for answering. To clarify I am trying to insert this string **Things I Like”   catalog \r\n** into a DB, and for some reason it is not working. Everything is works fine for any other string, and I am not getting any error message, it's just not appearing in the DB. So I thought it might be related to **”**.

Go easy on me guy!

**EDIT2**

```
      $interestTable = "5431591 1 Things I Like” <br>";

//problem lies here
        $count = 0;
        $interestTable = preg_replace_callback( '/<br>/', function( $match) use( $tagName, &$count) {
            return $tagName[$count++][0] . ' ' . PHP_EOL;
        }, $interestTable);


    //$interestTable = "5431591 1 Things I Like” catalog \r\n" after format

        $interestTable = mysql_real_escape_string($interestTable);

        echo $interestTable;


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name(userID,storyID,rank, storyType, interestTable)VALUES('$userID','$storyID','$rank','$storyType','$interestTable')", $dbh1);
```

**EDIT3** I was not mistaken, I changed the string from **Things I Like” catalog \r\n** to **Things I AA catalog \r\n** and it worked. I have no idea why this happens, maybe something gets messed up with the encoding after converting to a string but I am not sure. All I know for sure that after removing **”** from the string, everything works fine

Comment: Stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: This behavior is by design; those quotes are harmless.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Any **reason** you want to "fix" this?

Comment: Show the code. And define "not appearing" more clearly

Comment: Show the code with which you are trying to insert `Things I Like” \r\n catalog` string into table and nothing else.

Comment: inserting the string normally works fine, inserting the string that I got after the format does not. That's why I wrote you all the code.

Comment: nobody ever knows what is your string and what does it looks like after format. So, nobody can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: the output after the format is the `5431591 1 Things I Like” catalog \r\n` as I mentioned in my post/comments (edited my code as well)

Comment: After testing around the problem lies with `preg_replace_callback` I will comment the code

Comment: I think you don't need no preg nor replace, nor callback. What you're trying to achieve with such a monster function? Are you sure you need it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, it turns out to be an encounding problem.

After using **utf8_encode** (http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) on my string everything worked fine.

Thank you all for you help (especially Polynomial).

Answer (score 5):

Yup. Never rely on black-listing mechanisms like that for safety. It's broken, and can result in some interesting SQL injections:

```
$query = "SELECT id, title, body FROM posts WHERE id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

This can still be injected:

```
1 OR 1=1
```

Resulting in:

```
SELECT id, title, body FROM posts WHERE id = 1 OR 1=1
```

All results are returned. Not convinced this is bad? Ok...

```
1 OR 1=1 UNION SELECT id, username, password FROM users
```

Whoops!

Why is this injectable? The developer just forgot to quote the numeric ID. If you can *ever* see yourself making this mistake, you should seek a better solution.

---

My advice? Stop using string concatenation, stop using the deprecated `mysql_` functions, and shift to MySQLi or PDO with parameterised queries, where content is explicitly separated from query language.

Comment: to add 2 quotes to your query is actually much simpler than moving to parameterized queries :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes, but that's **not the point**. Can you guarantee you're going to catch every "gotcha" like this? Almost every application I test that falls to SQL injection does so because a developer forgot to escape a parameter, or improperly escaped it, and *not* because they were ignorant of the security issues. It's *significantly* safer to go for MySQLi or PDO. Source: Two decades of software development, many years of security research, work in penetration testing, and 30k rep on [Sec.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Agree. However, you can fake prepared statements with old mysql ext as well. So, this one have to be an emphasis, not mere API, which won't do any good just by itself.

Comment: "you can fake prepared statements with old mysql ext as well" - no, this is semantically not the case. Prepared statements work by separating the data out at the SQL protocol layer, thus entirely negating the potential for SQL injection attacks. The database is actively aware of the difference between data and query language. Any other mechanisms would be little more than blacklisting / filtering techniques.

Comment: Please. Choose one argument. **If** the point is that one can forget to format a variable properly and using prepared statement is a remedy, **then** it doesn't matter if that prepared statement being native or mere faked.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm making two points: 1) blacklist protection is flawed from a technical perspective since it doesn't actually prevent injection, and 2) developers will miss nuanced issues like this. You're basically saying "ok, so `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't actually prevent SQL injections, so let's use a *different* blacklisting technique!". That's not the way to solve the problem. You're advocating fixing the "I can't eat soup with a knife" problem by using a fork, instead of just switching to a spoon.

Comment: If it were possible I would down vote your first comment here @YourCommonSense.

Comment: Dunno what blacklisting you are talking about. As a matter of fact, mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do neither with "blacklisting", nor with protection at all. It is merely formatting facility. And it is doing its job well. Proper formatting of a string literal is not an "eating soup with a knife" by any means. It is pretty regular feature of any database. So, if I have a faked prepared statement that formats string literal properly, it would be as safe as using native prepared statement.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes, that's the case, and I was being overly generic. But with such escaping you're reliant on developers getting it right every time in a situation where there *can* be unusual issues, e.g. the issue with quoteless values. Using parameters solves the problem once and for all by removing the issue. I think we're generally agreeing on what *can* be done, but my overriding point is that prepared statements are an absolute solution (within reason) instead of a potentially problematic solution.

Comment: I told you already I agree with you on using prepared statements. However I disagree with your point stating that only *native* prepared statements are safe. So I said: " So, this one [i.e. using prepared statements] have to be an emphasis, not mere API, which won't do any good just by itself. "

Comment: Now that we have solved this let's all sit around the campfire and enjoy some marshmallows!

Comment: @LucasKauffman while you both are enjoying your marshmallows, can you please help me with my issue :(

Answer (score 3):

Curly quotes don't need to be escaped, as they have no special meaning to MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

That's because "smart" quotes are not recognised as quotes by the MySQL engine, and therefore pose absolutely no risk of injection attacks.

Comment: This is what I thought, but for some reason I cannot insert `Things I Like  \r\n` catalog into a catalog. Everything is works fine for any other string.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape `“` or `”`. There is nothing to fix.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_` functions are no longer maintained and are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0

You don't however need to escape `“` or `”`. These aren't recognised by MySQL as quotes.

I would suggest you use the PDO or MySQLi extension's when connecting to a MySQL database.